# What is $\frac{1}{\aleph_{\text{0}}}$?

Tags: cardinals, uniform-distribution

If you have a uniform distribution over the set of natural numbers, what is the probability of any of the numbers being picked? Can you think of it in terms of $\frac{1}{\aleph_{\text{0}}}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There is no such thing as uniform distribution on the set of natural numbers and $\frac{1}{\aleph_{\text{0}}}$ has no meaning.

Comment: If you choose $n$ uniformly from $1$ to $N$, many results have an $N\to\infty$ limit. But, as @geetha290krm noted, you can't literally sample $\Bbb N$ uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated, because there is a problem - $\frac{1}{\aleph_{\text{0}}}$ is undefined. This is because for any finite cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$. If $\kappa$ was infinite, $\kappa \aleph_0 = \max(\kappa,\aleph_0)$. Therefore, there does not exist a $\kappa$ such that $\kappa \aleph_0 = 1$. Note that $\aleph_0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, try upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot upvote though. It says I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Is this related to how $\frac{1}{\infty}$ is undefined, in general?

Comment: @Gabriel No problem. You can earn reputation by getting upvotes, accepting answers and much more.

Comment: @Gabriel Actually, if you use the affinely extended real number system, then \frac{1}{\infty} is defined to be $0$. See this article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: @Gabriel So in short, **this is unrelated**.